# Adjusting size of parent div containing scaled image

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-transforms

I'm currently trying to use `transform: scale()` to display crisp/clear responsive images. It works but unfortunately, parent containers don't seem to adjust to the scaled down image. See this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jL5u85jy/ The div seems to take up the space of the original size of the image instead of the newly scaled down one.

Is there a way of making a parent container adjust to a scaled image without setting a specific height for example? Any tips or suggestions are welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/jL5u85jy/2)

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Just the image should be scaled down, not the entire div.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xz2ajo83/ like this? or https://jsfiddle.net/xz2ajo83/1/ like this ?

Comment: In both examples the container was scaled down as well. I only want the the image to be scaled down however, so that other elements within the container div aren't affected.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, your problem come from the fact that images scaled with `transform: scale()` *still take up the same amount of space at their un-scaled counter parts.*

Which is cool because we can scale stuff in place with affecting document flow. But in your case it's a hindrance. Is there a reason you don't want to just scale the width?

It looks just as crisp to me?
[image]

```css
.container {
  background:blue;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
.scaled-image {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
     -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
      -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
       -o-transform: scale(0.5);
          transform: scale(0.5);
}
.scaled-width-image {
width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Scaled .5 </h2>
<div class="container">
  <img class="scaled-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/shBwMW4.jpg" />
</div>

<h2>width: 250px; (half of its original 500px width) </h2>
<div class="container">
  <img class="scaled-width-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/shBwMW4.jpg" />
</div>

<h2>Original</h2>
<div class="container">
  <img class="regular-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/shBwMW4.jpg" />
</div>
```